# Warning: filesize() [<a href='function.filesize'>function.filesize</a>]: stat failed for C:\wamp\www\Graph\php\php.txt

Tags: php

i am making a code for sending a mail with attachment.
But i am getting this error for file size and also getting following  errors:

```
Warning: fopen(C:\wamp\www\Graph\php\php.txt) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream:

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

I am beginner to this, kindly try to resolve my problem.
here is my code:

```
<?php
       mail_attachment('php.txt', 'C:\\wamp\\www\\Graph\\php\\', 'saurabh.d.sharma@ericsson.com',
                           'saurabh.d.sharma@ericsson.com', 'Saurabh Sharma D', 'saurabh.d.sharma@ericsson.com',
                           'Hello Mail Send With PHP', 'Please find the attached');
                          // mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message);
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    ini_set('sendmail_from', 'saurabh.d.sharma@ericsson.com');
    ini_set( 'SMTP', "smtp.internal.ericsson.com" );
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does `C:\wamp\www\Graph\php\php.txt` exist? Is it readable?

Comment: The first function to open the file (`fopen()`) is failing. That's what causes the other errors to appear. Their text is pretty self explanatory. Make sure `C:\wamp\www\Graph\php\php.txt` exists and is readable by PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Your script cannot find (or read) the file `C:\wamp\www\Graph\php\php.txt`

Comment: yes, you are right. Now i changed the file, now its not giving any error, but the attachment i am receiving in mail is of 64B is completely blank. what's that issue?

Comment: You don't include the content in the mail() call.  See your third argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the specified file can be opened:

```
$file = $path.$filename;
if ($handle = fopen($file, "r")) {
  $file_size = filesize($file);
  $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
  fclose($handle);
}
else {
  die("Error reading file: " . $file);
}
```

Comment: Thomas. i just tried to open this, but its showing complete blank.

Comment: i added die too, but again its showing Blank page in my browser

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: problem occurring is that the code is sending an empty attachment of 0 Byte. I'm not getting its exact cause, that why this happening.